# How can I run multiple Laravel commands simultaneously?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, parallel-processing

I need to run the same Laravel command with different parameters 20 times simultaneously, how can I automate this? It is like: 
`php artisan do-command 1`, `php artisan do-command 2`,`php artisan do-command 3`, ... `php artisan do-command 20`? 
Also, will my laptop with i7-7500u and 8gb of ram enough to run 20-100 processes?

**!!!UPDATE!!!**

after the first answer i created an sh file:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 for i in {1..20}
    php artisan do-command $i &
```

but it throws an error `syntax error near unexpected token "php"`

Comment: Maybe you could use a bash script?

Comment: @Sergio what would be the correct bash with the same command with arguments ranging 1-20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can add `&` to end of the command for running a command on the background, for example

```
for i in {1..20} do
    artisan do-command $i &
done
```

Comment: it says `syntax error near unexpected token `php'` in the line php artisan do-command